# Shift() elements from an array and push() into another

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to do something like drawing cards.

I have an array with 52 elements (deck[]), and I want to remove the first 13 elements and put them into another array, lets say player1[].

Then remove the next 13 elements and put them into player2[]...and so on.

I did this:

```
var deck = [], player1 = [], player2 = [], player3 = [], player4 = [];

function distributeCards(){
  for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){               
    for(var j = 0; j < 13; j++){
      player+i.push(deck.shift(j));
    }
  }
}
```

The array variables are declared outside, because I have to access them in other functions.

It says player is not defined...how should I write this?

Comment: What you want is a dynamic variable name: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: @ChristianVarga: The only dynamic variable names are global variables. People usually don't like to pollute the global space that much.

Comment: @squint That's not true; you can use `eval()` to generate a dynamic variable name (as described in the link I posted).

Comment: @ChristianVarga: That isn't truly a dynamic variable name (as in a language feature). That's simply evaluating a program and injecting it into the current scope. Not to mention its undesirable side-effects.

Comment: @squint You're just clawing at technicalities. What's your point? Whether it's a language feature or not, it allows you to create a dynamic variable name. Also, I'm curious - what would be the undesirable side-effects if used in the OPs scenario?

Comment: The problem with your comment is that you suggest he needs something that he doesn't. Now if JavaScript *actually* had dynamic variables (beyond globals), you'd be correct. Because it doesn't, one would have to resort to *mimicking* them with `eval` to take your advice. There are *much* better solutions for JS. Programming is *all* about technicalities. As to the problem with `eval`, it destroys optimizations in modern JS engines. OP's scenario is irrelevant. Give people bad advice and they'll continue to do it in other scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make up variable name with that. Instead, you should consider using array to store player's card, so you can dynamically reference each of the player's deck like this:

```
var deck = [];
var numOfPlayers = 4;
var players = new Array(numOfPlayers);

function distributeCards(){
  for(var i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++){ 
    players[i] = [];              
    for(var j = 0; j < 13; j++){
      players[i].push(deck.shift(j));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even though your solution is better, for the sake of correctness I just want to point out that you _can_ do what the OP suggested - see my comment above.

Comment: Yes, you can do that way. Your link is generically useful. However, it's more suitable to use array for this purpose.

Comment: @thefourtheye Very thoughtfully suggestion. Let me update it.

Comment: @TaoP.R. Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me why `alert(players[0][0].id);` doesn't work? I created my deck[] by doing `var deck = table.children;` because I already have the card elements on the table. It says "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

Comment: @razoes Have you populated the `deck` beforehand? I guess you will run into this situation when your `deck` variable is not filled before calling `distributeCards()`.

Comment: @TaoP.R. As I said, your solution is better. I'm just pointing out that your statement (_"You can't make up variable name with that"_) is not true/correct. You _can_ have dynamic variables in javascript.

Comment: @TaoP.R. Thanks. This worked out for what I needed it to. Only thing I changed was in `shift(j)` I removed the `j`. It was other member sugestion and does work.